# Error importing auto_arima from pyramid

Tags: python, data-science, pyramid-analytics

Trying to use pyramid's auto arima function and getting nowhere.

Importing the whole class:

```
import pyramid



stepwise_fit = auto_arima(df.Weighted_Price, start_p=0, start_q=0, max_p=10, max_q=10, m=1,
                      start_P=0, seasonal=True, trace=True,
                      error_action='ignore',  # don't want to know if an order does not work
                      suppress_warnings=True,  # don't want convergence warnings
                      stepwise=True)  # set to stepwise
```

I get error message:

```
NameError: name 'auto_arima' is not defined
```

Fine, then let's import that specific package from pyramid.

```
from pyramid.arima import auto_arima
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last) RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xb but this
>   version of numpy is 0xa
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 #trying to import pyramid
>   ----> 2 from pyramid.arima import auto_arima
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/arima/**init**.py in
>   ()
>         3 # Author: Taylor Smith 
>         4 
>   ----> 5 from .approx import *
>         6 from .arima import *
>         7 from .auto import *
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/arima/approx.py in
>   ()
>        16 # and since the platform might name the .so file something funky (like
>        17 # _arima.cpython-35m-darwin.so), import this absolutely and not relatively.
>   ---> 18 from pyramid.arima._arima import C_Approx
>        19 
>        20 **all** = [
>
> ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

After importing numpy, or even after just running the block again, I get this error message when running `from pyramid.arima import auto_arima`

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 #trying to import pyramid
>   ----> 2 from pyramid import arima
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/arima/**init**.py in
>   ()
>         3 # Author: Taylor Smith 
>         4 
>   ----> 5 from .approx import *
>         6 from .arima import *
>         7 from .auto import *
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/arima/approx.py in
>   ()
>        16 # and since the platform might name the .so file something funky (like
>        17 # _arima.cpython-35m-darwin.so), import this absolutely and not relatively.
>   ---> 18 from pyramid.arima._arima import C_Approx
>        19 
>        20 **all** = [
>
> ImportError: cannot import name C_Approx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Environment: 
Windows 10
IDE: Pycharm
Python: 3.6

In Anaconda, create a new environment and then run:

```
pip install pyramid-arima
```

Now in your python code, you can use:

`from pyramid.arima import auto_arima`

Comment: Note that the updated versions are under the name `pmdarima`, see: https://github.com/tgsmith61591/pmdarima

Answer (score 19):

Try to install `pmdarima` by using `pip`:

```
pip install pmdarima
```

then in your python script use:

```
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
```

Answer (score 4):

use:

```
pip install pyramid-arima
```

You installed the web framework pyramid which is not your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: (Anaconda prompt)

```
$ conda create -n pmdissue23 --yes --quiet python=3.5 numpy scipy scikit-learn statsmodels
activate pmdissue23
(pmdissue23) $ pip install pmdarima
```

In anaconda navigator,

```
from pmdarima import auto_arima
```

Answer (score -3):

1. Try uninstalling numpy and install the latest version.
2. Try installing pyramid-arima from Anaconda.